# JavaScript code i have applied on a calendar plugin is not working only in December month

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The below code gives the output as if the user fill the effort it has show in green. it is achieved by adding a class. If the user's effort is rejected by the manager, it is should display in another color. It is achieved by adding a span. if the user's effort is pending it should be displayed in another color. It is also done by adding a class. But these are working only till november. only for december it is not working. can anybody help me please.

```
ProjectServices.getEmployeeEffortHrs(employeeId).then(function(data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function(data) {
        var effort_date = new Date(data.effort_date);
        var date = effort_date.getDate();
        var monthService = effort_date.getMonth()+1;
        var approvedStatus = data.approveStatus;
        var totalEffortHours = data.total_effort;
        jQuery('div.datetimepicker table.day-view tbody tr td').each(function(index){
            var str = $(this).text();
            if((str.substr(0,str.indexOf(' ')) == date) && selectedMonth == monthService){
                if(totalEffortHours <= 8){
                    $(this).removeClass('pending-hrs');
                    $(this).addClass('filled-hrs');
                    if (!$scope.mgrApprvemployeeId) {
                        $dates[index].selectable = false;
                    };
                }else {
                    $(this).removeClass('pending-hrs');
                    $(this).addClass('holiday-leave');
                    if (!$scope.mgrApprvemployeeId) {
                        $dates[index].selectable = false;
                    };
                };
                if(approvedStatus == "Reject"){
                    var stringDisplay = date+"<span class='rejected-timesheet'>"+"Rejected"+" </span>  ";
                    $dates[index].selectable = true;
                } else{
                    var stringDisplay = date+"<span>"+totalEffortHours +" hrs</span>";
                    $(this).selectable = true;
                };
                var escaped = $(this).text(stringDisplay).text();
                $(this).html(escaped.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
            }
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: can you show where are you setting selectedMonth?

Comment: var selectedMonth = rightFormDate.getMonth();
    var selectedYear = rightFormDate.getFullYear();
    if (currentMonth == selectedMonth && currentYear == selectedYear) {
      $rightDate.selectable = false;
    };

Comment: You are correct pavdro. The issue is with selectedMonth . When I print that in console, upto nivember it is showing properly. But for december, it isshowing zero. I dont know why. I am using ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I think the problem is in adding 1 to monthService.
I know it starts from 0, but doesn't look like you did the same to selectedMonth. So either add 1 to selectedMonth, or change calculations.Does that make sense?